# How to require excel 2010 workbook to be in specific filepath in order to open with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, filepath

I would like to require a workbook to be located in a specific file path to open. I am using VBA in excel 2010.

(Project / ThisWorkbook code: 
Header: Workbook / Open)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open
    FilePath
    'Runs file path check when workbook opened
End Sub
```

(Project / Modules / Module1
Header: (General) FilePath)

```
Sub FilePath()

If ActiveWorkbook.Path = ("path address") Then
    PathOk
Else
    MsgBox ("This is an Unauthorized copy of this file. Please contact Administrator"), vbOKOnly
    ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Problem is Workbook currently opens and runs `PathOk routine` evertime regardless of file path.

Comment: Your code works on my end. What scenario do you encounter what you describe above?

Answer (score 2):

To be sure you are checking the right workbook maybe you should do it like this:

In the "Thisworkbook" code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    FilePath Me
End Sub
```

In a standard code module:

```
Sub FilePath(WB As Workbook)

    If WB.Path = ("path address") Then
        PathOk
    Else
        MsgBox "This is an Unauthorized copy of this file. Please contact Administrator", _
                vbOKOnly + vbCritical 'So it looks more critical ;)

        ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```